# Call same method of different type

Tags: rust, traits

I have these two types:

```
pub struct A;

impl A {
   pub fn get<T>(&self) -> T {}
}

pub struct B;

impl B {
   pub fn get<T>(&self) -> T {}
}
```

I want to know what is the more idiomatic way to dynamically call the correct `get` method of both types, depending on a trait object.

```
pub trait MyCollection {}
impl MyCollection for A {}
impl MyCollection for B {}
```

Suppose this wrapper:

```
pub struct Wrapper {
    pub results: Vec<&dyn MyCollection>
}

impl Wrapper {
    pub fn new(incoming_data: Vec<impl MyCollection>) {
        Self {
            results: result.iter()
                .map(|row| row as &dyn MyCollection)
                .collect()
        }
    }
}
```

and here it's where I am getting lost designing the process.

I would like to call the correct `get` method, depending on the real type inside the elements of `impl MyCollection`.

Even tho I cast the objects that comes in the `incoming_data: Vec<impl MyCollection>` (because I can't type my struct with impl fancy statements), their original type it's only A or B. Right?

And the question is: what should I code on `MyCollection` trait to make it able to call the right get method and mantain my code as much generic as possible?

Is this even possible in Rust?

Edit: I forgot to mention that the types `A` and `B` are external.

Comment: The two `get` methods don't take `self` arguments, so it's unclear exactly how you plan to call them *on* objects in the first place. But if you want to be able to call `get` on `dyn MyCollection` objects, then `get` should be defined (with a `&self` or `&mut self` argument) *on* that trait.

Comment: my bad. It's corrected now

Comment: The `get` method needs to be on the trait in `dyn Trait` for you to call it. Also, `fn new() -> Self` should not take an `&self` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In its current form, no this is not possible. First, let's deal with the parts of the problem we *can* control. If you want multiple different types to implement the same method, you don't define the method in the object's inherent `impl`; Instead, you define it in the trait. So if you want `A::get` and `B::get` to be related to the `MyCollection` trait, you need to write this.

```
pub trait MyCollection {
  fn get<T>(&self) -> T;
}

pub struct A;

impl MyCollection for A {
  fn get<T>(&self) -> T { ... }
}

pub struct B;

impl MyCollection for B {
  fn get<T>(&self) -> T { ... }
}
```

Now the two `get` functions are related by the trait. We could write a function like this

```
fn get_as_int<C: MyCollection>(arg: &C) -> i32 {
  arg.get::<i32>()
}
```

However, this is compile-time dispatch. While it's good for a lot of situations, it's not going to suffice if you want to store a heterogeneous collection of data.

In order to be able to use a trait `MyCollection` as a `dyn MyCollection` trait object, it must be [object safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety). These are some common sense sanity rules that make it possible for Rust to construct a vtable (virtual function table) for the type. Among them, each (dispatchable) method must satisfy

> - Not have any type parameters (although lifetime parameters are allowed),

So your `get<T>` is right out, since it has a `T` type parameter. The reason for this is that Rust monomorphizes type parameters, so when you call `get::<i32>()`, Rust creates a new version of the `get` function which returns an `i32`. When Rust tries to make a trait object, it needs to create, in advance, all of the functions that could be called on the trait object and store them in the vtable. Since `get<T>` is actually an *infinite* class of functions, it can't ever do this, so we can't make trait objects.

If your intention is to have `MyCollection` store data of *some type*, whose type is known at compile-time (which is the most common way collections work), then you simply need to move the type argument to the trait level, not the function level. Your current trait

```
pub trait MyCollection {
  fn get<T>(&self) -> T;
}
```

says "`MyCollection` is the type of objects for which, for *any* type `T`, I can get a `T` out of it". It's not really clear how you plan to usefully implement this trait. What if the collection stores a `String` and I ask to `get::<u32>`? Is that a panic?

Instead, consider

```
pub trait MyCollection<T> {
  fn get(&self) -> T;
}
```

This says "`MyCollection<T>`, for some *specific* `T`, is a structure that I can get a `T` out of".

Now *this* `get` trait method doesn't have generic arguments, so the trait is object safe. We can store `&dyn MyCollection<i32>`, or `Box<dyn MyCollection<i32>>`, in a `Vec<...>` somewhere, because Rust only has to generate *one* method for the vtable. Then you would make `Wrapper` generic.

```
pub struct Wrapper<T> {
  pub results: Vec<&dyn MyCollection<T>>,
}
```

The broad point here is, if you want to keep track of the type of something, you need to use a type variable to do it in the types themselves. Your type variable was declared too late and made a very strong promise. With this new trait, we always know the type of the collection at compile-time safely.

Comment: Thanks, @Silvio Mayolo. I edited the post to reflect that `A` and `B` are external. So you can reduce you response according to that. Sorry for it.  I will study the last part of your post, because I guess that I can implement in in my real problem. This is the point where your answer starts to fit into my desired solution ``` your intention is to have MyCollection store data of some type, whose type is known at compile-time (which is the most common way collections work), then you simply need to move the type argument to the trait level, not the function level. Your current trait```

Comment: If you control `MyCollection`, you can have `MyCollection`'s `get` delegate to the respective inherent methods in the `impl MyCollection<T> for ...` blocks.

Comment: Yup. `MyCollection` takes in the constructor a collection of `impl MyCollection`. I casted the elements to the trait object. But I still can't figure out the correct syntax to call the external `get` methods. What I want to say is that I am not expecting to have logic inside my get method that calls the correct real `get` method. Even tho the elements are of type `&dyn MyCollection` we can ensure that are of the same type due to the `impl MyCollection`. RIght?

Comment: I'm not sure I followed that. There's no way to "downcast" in safe Rust, so once you've turned something into a `dyn`, you don't get the original type back. Period.

Comment: it's possible to downcast in safe Rust with `Any`

Comment: @AlexVergara *"I still can't figure out the correct syntax to call the external get methods"* - just call them: `self.get()` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c046742c3becf072476727f91899595d)). Method calls always use the inherent implementation if it exists (and is statically known), so it doesn't just recursively call itself.

Comment: you're right @kmdreko